# Getting the IDs of nodes on a single line to be placed in a single field in the attribute table

Tags: qgis

Is there anyway to find out the IDs of multiple nodes on a single line and place them in a single field? I'm trying to get the IDs of nodes that appear on their respective links to be placed in a single box.

For example, Line 50 has 4 nodes with IDs 12,13,14 and 15. How do i use the field calculator to put all 4 nodes (or more/less) to be placed into Node IDs with a comma separating each node ID?

Comment: Are the nodes already referenced in the line attribute table or the lines referenced in the nodes attribute table? Was a relation created?

Comment: @Victor Hey the nodes are partly referenced in the line attribute table in the sense that it only has the front and end node of the line itself, but do not have anything else in between. I'm thinking of using the x and y coordinates to filter them out, as the start x & y of the line will definitely be lesser than the x & y of the nodes, but the end x and y of the line will be greater. Will that work?

Comment: Do the nodes in the node layer correspond to actual nodes of the (poly)lines?

Comment: @Victor Yup, the nodes are extracted from the lines themselves.

Comment: Well, it must be possible with qgis and/or pygis but i do not know how. However, you can export your shp as csv with WKT geometry, use text to columns, perform some vlookup and concat magic to get your results, then re-import into qgis.

Comment: Would you accept an arcgis/arcpy answer? I just solved a similar problem using the intersect tool and then cursors to read and update the table based on those intersects. Unfortunately, I don't know how to translate this to qgis...

Comment: @Priscilla Can't do sorry but you could always leave it here for other people's reference :)